# Disable thumbnail preview on file upload menu

Tags: firefox, thumbnails, websites, upload

I want to disable thumbnail when I press "upload a file" in a browser.

I tried to remove the package tumbler, but it is still showing the picture.

[image]

Comment: It may be useful if you can edit your question to specify the browser that you are using.